# vee-validate different text-field values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I use vee-avlidate 3 and Nuxt.js

How can I make a rule that checks 2 text-field values are different ?

For example the `current_password` field should be different from `new_password` field.

**Password.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ invalid, validated, passes, validate }">
      <form>
        <ValidationProvider rules="required|min:6" v-slot="{ errors, valid }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="current_password"
            label="Current Password"
            type="password"
            :success="valid"
            :error-messages="errors"
          />
        </ValidationProvider>
        <ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, valid }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="new_password"
            label="New Password"
            type="password"
            :success="valid"
            :error-messages="errors"
          />
        </ValidationProvider>
      </form>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      current_password: "",
      new_password: "",
    };
  },
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    ValidationProvider
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show your current code

Comment: @depperm code added

Comment: I would look at the [docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#multiple-arguments) and make a rule to take 2 params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of the documentation for [cross field validation](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#cross-field-validation).  Essentially the steps are

1. Wrap the fields within the same `ValidationObserver` component.
2. Give each field a name property
3. Reference the target field name or vid value in the rules of the other.

For your code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ invalid, validated, passes, validate }">
      <form>
        <ValidationProvider rules="required|min:6" v-slot="{ errors, valid }" name='password'>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="current_password"
            label="Current Password"
            type="password"
            :success="valid"
            :error-messages="errors"
          />
        </ValidationProvider>
        <ValidationProvider rules="required|distinct:@password" v-slot="{ errors, valid }" name='new password'>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="new_password"
            label="New Password"
            type="password"
            :success="valid"
            :error-messages="errors"
          />
        </ValidationProvider>
      </form>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, Extend } from "vee-validate";

extend('distinct', {
  params: ['target'],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value !== target;
  },
  message: 'Fields can not be the same'
});

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      current_password: "",
      new_password: "",
    };
  },
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    ValidationProvider
  },
};
</script>
```